# Why did I lose with my pair of fives?

Tags: reading-hands, hand

Can you help me understand this situation:

[image: hand]

I held the 5⋄ 8♥ and thought that my pair of 5s would give me the victory?

Comment: @jon there is no flush, he was out-kicked.

Comment: What the hell was I looking at. Painkillers and SE don't mix.

Answer (score 3):

You've been counterfeited on the river.

Villain's best hand is: Q♥ Q♠ 6♥ 6♣ J⋄ (*two pair, Queens and Sixes, Jack kicker*)

Your best hand is: Q♥ Q♠ 6♥ 6♣ 8♥ (*two pair, Queens and Sixes, Eight kicker*)

Therefore, your pair of fives is irrelevant as it doesn't form part of your best hand, which cannot beat your opponent's best hand and so you lose at showdown.